# QWebView pass data from jQuery to Qt

Tags: qt, qwebview

I am loading a html page (view.html) into my `QWebView` which contains a table.

Inside `view.html` I've also got `jQuery` loaded, to track clicks on my table rows.
When a click is done i want to notify Qt so that i can take action on the click.

This is the `jQuery` i execute within `view.html`:

```
$("table").delegate('tr', 'click', function() {
    alert("You clicked my <tr> with ID# 123");

    // Now i want to let QT know that i have clicked the tr with ID# 123

});
```

How can i let Qt know that the `tr` with ID `123` was clicked?